# Modify SQL to get count of all titles with the same biblionumber

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to get the most popular titles borrowed at a library based on the number of times it has been borrowed. The code I am using is adopted from [koha SQL reports library](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/SQL_Reports_Circulation#Top_10_Circulating_Books) but it doesn't seem to give a count of titles but instead gives a count of items. I would like to have a count of all titles based on the biblionumber as I have attempted in the SQL code shown below.

```sql
SELECT
    biblio.title,
    biblio.author,
    biblio.biblionumber,
    COUNT(biblio.biblionumber) AS "count"
FROM statistics
LEFT JOIN items ON (statistics.itemnumber = items.itemnumber)
LEFT JOIN biblio ON (items.biblionumber = biblio.biblionumber)
WHERE
    (statistics.datetime BETWEEN '2023-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-07-31 23:59:59')
    AND statistics.type = 'issue'
    AND items.itype IN ('BK', 'REF', 'TH', 'RES')
GROUP BY statistics.itemnumber, biblio.title, biblio.author 
ORDER BY COUNT(biblio.biblionumber) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

The database schema for koha is here http://schema.koha-community.org/

As shown in the figure below, the title whose biblionumber is 83 should appear as one record with a total count of 11.[image]

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: And I assume you want to ORDER BY a result-set column. A column alias would be convenient.

Comment: I tried that and got " MySQL said: Documentation
#1056 - Can't group on 'count' "

Comment: Your SQL looks correct and therefore I'm guessing that this is a data issue. I would check to see whether the values in either the title or author columns have leading/trailing spaces or any non-printing characters (easy to test using a LEN function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT
    biblio.title,
    biblio.author,
    biblio.biblionumber,
    COUNT(biblio.biblionumber) AS "count"
FROM statistics,items,biblio
WHERE statistics.itemnumber = items.itemnumber 
AND items.biblionumber = biblio.biblionumber    
AND statistics.type = 'issue'
AND items.itype IN ('BK', 'REF', 'TH', 'RES')
AND (statistics.datetime BETWEEN '2023-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-07-31 23:59:59')
GROUP BY biblio.biblionumber, biblio.title, biblio.author 
ORDER BY COUNT(biblio.biblionumber) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Tested, it looks perfect. Asante sana @Sudipto Bhattacharya